# PyCharm autocomplete in folder with many projects, both py2 and py3

Tags: python, autocomplete, ide, pycharm

I work on django website with lots of components and modules.

In the same folder and git repository, I also have another closely related projects like data downloaders, transformers, validators, uploaders and utilities. Roots of all projects are many levels deep. Projects use both Python 3 and Python 2, because of some outdated dependencies.

Before today, autocomplete did not work for anything, except maybe major dependencies if I also install them system-wide. Every import was underlined in waved red.

Just now I went to "File/Settings/Project/Project Structure/Add content root", removed default root and added main django website. It works for site, but I can't add root directory since it 'overlaps', so I lost view of tree and this is not acceptable.

How to keep full intact view of source tree and still have autocomplete in all and every sub-project, be it main one or one-off utility ?

PyCharm version is 2016.2.3 (latest), community edition.